# How to increase EventProvider payload size?

Tags: windows, appfabric, etw

Is it possible to increase the payload size for user defined events in Appfabric ?
To achieve custom events, I am using the `EventProvider` class defined in the `System.Diagnostics.Eventing` namespace (sample [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee667248.aspx)).

As we can find on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382834.aspx),

*The maximum data size for the event is limited to 64 KB minus the size of the event headers. The event size is less if the session's buffer size is less and the session includes extended data items with the event.*

Just for your information, some of my custom events takes more than 64KB, because they contains a serialized copy of inputs and/or outputs. When the payload size is greater thant 64KB, the message is not written.

Comment: you can't .. just divide your messages into more sub logical messages.